# Checkboxes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a tabel with rows with checboxes in it. When I click on a checkbox, I want the value of the ID-attribute to be pushed into the object.

I have the following HTML-code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="info in test">
    <td>{{info.stracka}}</td>
    <td>{{info.tid}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="{{info.id}}" ng-model="compare.checkbox">
</tr>
```

As you can see, my ng-model connected to a compare object. How do I add the value of the ID-attribute to my compare object? And the ng-model seems to only be able to bind the value of one single checkbox to a variable in the controller. How can I solve this?

Here is my controller:

```
as.controller('Test', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, testFactory)
{   
    $http.get($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/test/test')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.test = data.data;
    });

    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.compare = {};
    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
        if(isValid) 
        {   
            /*testFactory.testFactoryMethod(function($http) {
                $scope.test = data;
            });*/
            $http.post($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/test', $scope.form)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.test.push($scope.form);
                $scope.test.push(data);
            }).error(function(data, status) {

            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: try ng-checked to manage the check

Comment: @chf: How do I get the value of the ID-attribut into the object?

Comment: Do you want to have ID-attribute value inside `$scope.compare.checkbox` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're binding all the checkboxes to `compare.checkbox`

if you add `$scope.compare.checkbox = [];` to the controller
and 
    instead use

`ng-model="compare.checkbox[info.tid]`

assuming `info.tid` is a number and is unique you should be able to access the checkbox from the controller by using

`$scope.compare.checkbox[thetidhere];`

Comment: When I write $scope.compare.checkbox = []; I get this error messagE: Error: $scope.compare is undefined

Comment: you first need to     $scope.compare = {}; then $scope.compare.checkbox = [];

Comment: How can I see ALL the ids in $scope.compare?

Comment: Loop through the array using a for loop

Answer (score 0):

To push additional data you should use `ng-click` in following way:

```
<input 
    type="checkbox" id="{{info.id}}" 
    ng-model="compare.checkbox" 
    ng-click="compare.id_attribute = info.id" 
/>
```

Comment: Thank you. How should the controller look like? When I click on a checkbox, all the checboxes are selected instead, which is wrong.

Comment: Thats because you are working with only one model for all of them. I dont know much about your application, but maybe it will be enought to delete model for this checkboxs. Remove `ng-model="compare.checkbox"`